# Itext7 dynamic pdf download returns -Document has no pages on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, pdf-generation, itext7

I have a situation where I've used the Itext7 library for generating pdf's on a .net core app.
As far as im aware code works well when Im running the application locally i.e I can download pdf's without any issues. (This pdf is dynamically generated).
But once i deploy the application to a remote server i get an error  `PdfException Document has no pages`
Is there anything I need to do on  the server or does this have to do with browser policy that I may need to change ?

Comment: More information is needed. Let's start with the minimal code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently , the issue was that I  was calling into an Image file that I use for generating the pdf . This file was saved locally on my drive and wasn't available on the sever end hence the pdf doesn't get created .
I basically relocated the image file into the wwwroot/images folder and called it from there and there  you have it ... I solved my own problem